# When should I use Firebase.ServerValue.Timestamp and Firebase.database.ServerValue.Timestamp in Firebase?

Tags: firebase

What is the difference between the two, and when should I use the Firebase.ServerValue.Timestamp and Firebase.database.ServerValue.Timestamp since they both give unix time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know `Firebase.ServerValue.Timestamp` is just the old class, and not used anymore.

For code with recent SDKs (version 3.0 and later), use [`Firebase.database.ServerValue.Timestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue#.TIMESTAMP).